# Entity Framework TPH bug

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this Entity :

```
public class Soggetti
{
    public Soggetti()
    {
    }

    public int sersog { get; set; }
    string descri { get; set; }

}

public class SoggettiMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Soggetti>
{
    public SoggettiMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.sersog);

        this.Property(t => t.descri)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(200);

        this.ToTable("soggetti");
        this.Property(t => t.sersog).HasColumnName("sersog");
        this.Property(t => t.descri).HasColumnName("descri");

    }
}
```

And this:

```
 public class Enti : Soggetti
{
    public Enti()
    {

    }
    public int serent { get; set; }
    public string denuff { get; set; }
}



 public class entiMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Enti>
{
    public entiMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.serent);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.denuff)
            .HasMaxLength(150);


        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("enti");
        this.Property(t => t.denuff).HasColumnName("denuff");
        this.Property(t => t.serent).HasColumnName("serent");

    }
}
```

If try this linq code :

```
from e in Enti select e
```

result is ok, nut if try this :

```
Enti.Find(1)
```

I have an error because where's sql code goes by sersog and not serent

```
WHERE [Extent1].[sersog] = @p0
```

In the Enti's entity map i've defined serent with HasKey property and not sersog that is defined with HasKey property in soggetti class

Comment: This is not TPH. In TPH, with an inheritance relationship like this, both entities are stored in the same Table (because they are in the same inheritance hierarchy). This means that they MUST use the same key. It sounds like this is not the behavior you want. Can you give us more information about your use case?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a mistake,it is a Table per Type (TPT) like this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)
The difference is in the foreign key. Relation key into example is the primary key, in my example not

Comment: As you see in that link, the inherited type tables (CreditCards and BankAccounts) use the same PK (BillingDetail) as the base type. If you want different keys, it likely shouldn't be an inheritance relationship. Why not just add a navigation property from Enti to Soggetti instead?

Comment: The database isn't new, and Enti is a subclass of soggetti.
I will add a navigation property instead inheritance.
Thanks for reply